# Is there a way to clear this node-modules error in React or do I re-install from scratch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, webpack

I was trying to install react router when my vscode terminal showed some issues so I used `npm audit fix --force` after which it just showed more issues. I've deleted node-modules and reinstalled but its still the same thing. Now the app page is displaying this.

[image: Screenshot of VSCode]

Comment: Looks like you're missing an `import React from 'react'` in your `./src/Home.js`...

Comment: Downvoting because the code and error messages are in an image. Please copy-paste the text into your question so people with the same issue in the future can find your question on Google.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the cache present in npm, you need to run the command. If it doesn't work, run the force clean method since the cache is not cleared simply. See the below command.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

The clean command show above clears all the data present in your cache folder. To verify whether your cache is cleared or not, you need to use the below command.

```
npm cache verify
```

After that run the installation command.